# Source is not a valid model

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-amplify

I have this code:

```
 let result = await API.graphql<GraphQLQuery<CreatecommunityMutation>>(graphqlOperation(createcommunity, {
                    ...

}))
```

It creates an `Group` inside an lambda and returns it. When i try to save something it says its not valid model:

`Datastore.save(Group.copyOf(result.data.createcommunity, m => {}))`

Answer (score 0):

Well, there is besides `Group.copyOf` an other method to use, its called `fromJSON`

You can use `Group.fromJSON` to copy your json and convert it into an model.
In case you use typescript you will need to ignore the error that it cant find it:

```
//ts-ignore
Group.fromJSON(...)
```